# post jquery array to php page when checking checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, post

i have dynamic number of checkboxes and a button to post the checked elements to another page .. here is the code:

```
<div class="overSelect"></div>
<div id="checkboxes<?php echo $aa['id']; ?>">
<?php
    $pid = select::property($aa['name']); 
    $arr2 = select::properties($pid);
    $cc = 1;
    foreach ($arr2 as $aa2) { ?>
    <div style="padding-right: 20px" class="row"><label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $aa2['name'] ?>" name="checks<?php echo $aa['id'] ?>[]"id="check<?php echo $aa['id']; ?>"><?php echo $aa2['name'] ?>
    </label></div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="update-all"onclick="update_all('prop_id<?php echo $aa['id']; ?><?php $counter; ?>','checks<?php echo $aa['id'] ?>')"id="btn-all<?php echo $aa['id']; ?><?php $counter; ?><?php echo $p['id']; ?>">save</a>
```

i tried this code but it is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function update_all(a, b) {
        var aa = document.getElementById(a).value;
        var values = new Array();
        $("input:checkbox[name=b]").each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")){
            values.push($(this).val());
            }
        });
        alert(aa);
        alert(values.length);
        alert(values);
    }
</script>
```

if the checkboxes checked .. it's value will be added to the array and posted to php page
any help please .. thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you put the html within a `<form>` and call the `submit()` method of the form when you have updated all values?

Comment: @RichardBernards ok i will try this idea. thanks bro